# Two size features in ggplot (mean + std)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got a ggplot where I plot three or more variables. The third one is represented by e.g. the size of its numerical values (mean values).

[image: img]

I would like to add std values as transparent bigger dots around the already present dots and the size of the additional dots should reflect their magnitude in std. I could simply add another `geom_point()` but even when I define both size intervals (std intervals are bigger than the mean intervals) it would give aberrant impressions when the std values always have a minimum size. Is this understandable and somehow possible?

How it should or could look like:

[image: img2]

What I would like to have is: No matter how big the mean value or its dot is, a small std should surround it but less than a big std.

edit:

```
dput(df_experiment)
structure(list(n = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4), time = c(10080, 10095, 10110, 
10125, 0, 15, 0, 15, 120, 135, 60, 75, 100, 115, 130, 145, 0, 
15, 0, 15, 60, 75, 45, 60), weight = c(15.5, 23.8, 15.7, 23.3, 
13, 22, 13, 21, 16, 24, 19, 25, 21, 27, 21, 27, 22, 29, 23, 29, 
25, 26, 25, 26), height = c(26.61, 25.23, 23.03, 23.64, 13.64, 
11.84, 13.26, 10.77, 14.01, 15, 13, 13.3, 27.5, 25.92, 18.83, 
19.26, 18.93, 21.43, 16.11, 19.5, 13.01, 13.35, 15.12, 12.92), 
    length = c(47.8, 65.8, 36.7, 63.8, 63, 68, 62, 70.6, 59.8, 
    63.7, 69.3, 66.5, 63.6, 74.2, 67.8, 77.9, 68.1, 78.2, 75.6, 
    81, 67.5, 68.7, 67.5, 68.7), sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
    "E"), class = "factor"), height_set = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("100", "40", "70"
    ), class = "factor"), weight_set = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("10", "15", "20", "25"
    ), class = "factor"), std = c(0.812703886069357, 0.782337151234969, 
    0.602131422609091, 0.69466593535617, 0.580281280446798, 0.430830358527601, 
    0.768334821797907, 0.577222188469023, 0.683016336522996, 
    0.277622280176729, 0.566097403643653, 0.845317166764289, 
    0.328095777193084, 0.83994737197645, 0.874583127908409, 0.424604137195274, 
    0.023338885512203, 0.0864457285497338, 0.929015822941437, 
    0.0764572839252651, 0.194908467587084, 0.65600896649994, 
    0.233351909788325, 0.255731456680223)), row.names = c(NA, 
24L), class = "data.frame")
```

`df_experiment$std` is arbitrary as I have to add these information, yet. That's why I provided random numbers. I'm using

```
df_experiment %>%
            ggplot() + 
            #geom_point(aes(x = weight, y = height, color = length, size = std), alpha = 0.9) +
            #scale_size_continuous(range = c(6,18)) +
            geom_point(aes(x = weight, y = height, color = length, size = time), alpha = 0.8) +
            scale_color_continuous(trans='reverse') +
            scale_size_continuous(range = c(3,9)) +
            xlab("weight") + ylab("height") +
            ggtitle("length") +
            theme_tq()
```

Comment: it would helpful if you can provide `dput(df)`

Comment: Perhaps you could also include a sketch of the final result and some definition of big and small stds.

Comment: Hi, I added data and a sketch, is this comprehensible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ggnewscale` to define a new size scale and then have the limits of the point size range for the mean be smaller than the limits of the point size range for the std.

```r
df_experiment <- structure(list(n = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4), time = c(10080, 10095, 10110, 
10125, 0, 15, 0, 15, 120, 135, 60, 75, 100, 115, 130, 145, 0, 
15, 0, 15, 60, 75, 45, 60), weight = c(15.5, 23.8, 15.7, 23.3, 
13, 22, 13, 21, 16, 24, 19, 25, 21, 27, 21, 27, 22, 29, 23, 29, 
25, 26, 25, 26), height = c(26.61, 25.23, 23.03, 23.64, 13.64, 
11.84, 13.26, 10.77, 14.01, 15, 13, 13.3, 27.5, 25.92, 18.83, 
19.26, 18.93, 21.43, 16.11, 19.5, 13.01, 13.35, 15.12, 12.92), 
    length = c(47.8, 65.8, 36.7, 63.8, 63, 68, 62, 70.6, 59.8, 
    63.7, 69.3, 66.5, 63.6, 74.2, 67.8, 77.9, 68.1, 78.2, 75.6, 
    81, 67.5, 68.7, 67.5, 68.7), sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
    "E"), class = "factor"), height_set = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("100", "40", "70"
    ), class = "factor"), weight_set = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("10", "15", "20", "25"
    ), class = "factor"), std = c(0.812703886069357, 0.782337151234969, 
    0.602131422609091, 0.69466593535617, 0.580281280446798, 0.430830358527601, 
    0.768334821797907, 0.577222188469023, 0.683016336522996, 
    0.277622280176729, 0.566097403643653, 0.845317166764289, 
    0.328095777193084, 0.83994737197645, 0.874583127908409, 0.424604137195274, 
    0.023338885512203, 0.0864457285497338, 0.929015822941437, 
    0.0764572839252651, 0.194908467587084, 0.65600896649994, 
    0.233351909788325, 0.255731456680223)), row.names = c(NA, 
24L), class = "data.frame")
```

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
df_experiment %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = weight, y = height, color = length, size = std), alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(6,10)) +
  new_scale("size") + 
  geom_point(aes(x = weight, y = height, color = length, size = time), alpha = 0.9) +
  scale_color_continuous(trans='reverse') +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1,5)) +
  xlab("weight") + ylab("height") +
  ggtitle("length")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be using `geom_circle()` from the `ggforce`-package: https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_circle.html

```
library(ggforce)
ggplot(data = df_experiment) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = weight, y = height, color = length, size = time), alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_color_continuous(trans='reverse') +
  xlab("weight") + ylab("height") +
  ggtitle("length") +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = weight, y0 = height,r = std, fill = length), alpha = 0.25)
```

[image]

the plot needs some further adjustments of course, but it's one possible solution.